# Gradle: How to Refer to the Input of Another Task?

Tags: gradle

### Question In Short

In the configuration of one Gradle task, how can I refer to the input of another task?

### What I’ve Tried

Consider the following (contrived) sample `build.gradle` file (stored under `/tmp/foo`) where I’d like to use the same task input value in two different tasks:

```java
task task1 {
  def myInput = projectDir  // (or any other directory)
  inputs.dir(myInput).withPropertyName('t1Input')
  doLast {
    println myInput
  }
}

task task2 {
  dependsOn task1
  def myInput = task1.inputs.properties['t1Input']
  inputs.dir(myInput).withPropertyName('t2Input')
  doLast {
    println myInput
  }
}
```

In `task2` I would like to use the same input as in `task1`. However, when I run this build with `./gradlew --console=verbose --warning-mode=all task2` I get:

```
> Task :task1 
/tmp/foo
> Task :task2 
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':task2'. Registering invalid inputs and outputs via TaskInputs and TaskOutputs methods has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
 - No value has been specified for property 't2Input'.
null
```

It seems that my task input property named `t1Input` from `task1` is not available via `task1.inputs.properties` ([Javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#properties-java.util.Map-)).

FWIW, I use Gradle 4.6.

Comment: Typically one would explicitly factor this common configuration out - I'm curious what the use-case is for this?

Comment: The use case is not that fancy: I simply have multiple tasks which have the same configuration file as an input. In the above example I could declare the file at the top level of the build script, e.g., `def myInput = projectDir`, and then use the global variable `myInput` in the two tasks. But that didn’t feel right somehow, so I looked for other ways of doing it – and was surprised that the seemingly more “natural” `task1.inputs.properties` solution didn’t work ;-)